# Unable to find beacon using Albeacon library

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

I have created an android application which is used to scan for beacons. Just for testing purposes, I created an activity start for scanning of beacons using Albeacon library and then show beacons ids but it seems to be not working. Here is my code:

```
   private void init() {
            try {
                if (beaconManager != null && monitoringRegion != null) {
                    displayOnActivity("Already running");
                    return;
                }
                displayOnActivity("starting with init method..");
              beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

                beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(3000l);
                beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);;

                 beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();

            beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(RANGE_NOTIFIER);
                beaconManager.setUseTrackingCache(false);
             backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

             monitoringRegion = new Region("DefaultRegion", null, null, null);
                 beaconManager.bind(this);
                beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(monitoringRegion);
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(monitoringRegion);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to start beacon monitoring.. ", e);
            }
        }

 @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        displayOnActivity("onBeaconServiceConnect activated");
        beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BeaconApplication got enter region observation");
                try {
                    if (beaconManager != null)
                        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception while ranging beacon", e);
                 }
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                displayOnActivity("Exit region with beacon");
                try {
                    if (beaconManager != null)
                        beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                    flushBeaconsNotificationsForRegion(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception while stop ranging beacon", e);
                 }
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            }
        });

        try {
            if (monitoringRegion != null)
                beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(monitoringRegion);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while startMonitoringReagion.. " + e);
        }
    }


 final RangeNotifier RANGE_NOTIFIER = new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                String beaconKey = beacon.getId1().toString();
                if (!beaconIdToSeenTimestampMap.containsKey(beaconKey)) {
                    long fromTimestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                    displayOnActivity("Beacon " + beaconKey + " discovered");
                    beaconIdToSeenTimestampMap.put(beaconKey, fromTimestamp);
                    beaconsRSSISamplingMap.put(beaconKey, Collections.<Integer>emptyList());
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

This is a console log which I can see:

```
W/BeaconManager: Setting a short backgroundBetweenScanPeriod has no effect on Android 8+, which is limited to scanning every ~15 minutes
W/BeaconManager: The BeaconManager is not bound to the service.  Call beaconManager.bind(BeaconConsumer consumer) and wait for a callback to onBeaconServiceConnect()
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
W/ality.hp.beaco: Class org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanState failed lock verification and will run slower.
W/ality.hp.beaco: Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
W/ality.hp.beaco: and incorrect proguard optimizations.
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
W/JobInfo: Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
W/JobInfo: Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
W/JobInfo: Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
I/CycledLeScanner: Using Android O scanner
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob$1@4ec0aac
I/ScanJob: scanJob version 2.16.2 is starting up on the main process
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/DistanceConfigFetcher: Can't reach server
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot updated distance models from online database at java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
W/JobInfo: Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
I/ScanJob: onStopJob called for immediate scan org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@6518055
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Using periodicScanJobId from manifest: 208352940
W/JobInfo: Requested interval +5m0s0ms for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +15m0s0ms
W/JobInfo: Requested flex 0 for job 208352940 is too small; raising to +5m0s0ms
I/CycledLeScanner: Using Android O scanner
I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939
I/ScanJob: Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob$1@eb1514b
I/ScanJob: scanJob version 2.16.2 is starting up on the main process
W/DistanceConfigFetcher: Can't reach server
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot updated distance models from online database at java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
```

Can someone tell me the reason why no results are showing?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the code to start monitoring and ranging into the `onBeavonServiceConnected`

```
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(monitoringRegion);                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(monitoringRegion);
```

Understand that the call to bind is asynchronous, and if not complete, this error will be logged:

```
Log.e(TAG, "unable to start beacon monitoring.. ", e);
```

Other things to check:

1. Make sure you have location permission granted. This must be dynamically obtained from the user in code on Android 6+.
2. Make sure bluetooth and location are turned on.

Comment: Well, I resolved this by changing targetSdkVersion=21. As I have all required permission in my Manifest file but don't know why it is not working when targetSdkVersion set to 24 in gradle file. 
It may be because of my app is running in the background so Bluetooth background scanning is restricted by android in newer SDKversion.

Comment: When Google released Android 6, they allowed apps with targetSdkVersion 22 and earlier to be allowed to scan bluetooth in the *foreground only* for backward compatibility purposes.  Backgrounds scanning was blocked, however, without obtaining the dynamic location permission from the user.  I do not know if later versions of Android (e.g. 7-9) continue to honor this backward compatibility.  I suggest you simply implement the dynamic permission request.  See [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html)